# Adding a CSS margin to Foundation columns?

Tags: javascript, css, zurb-foundation

I'm having some trouble adding margins and keeping the responsiveness in columns when using Foundation 5.

At current, here's the code and a screenshot of what multiples of this look like together.

```
<div class="large-3 medium-3 columns panel coupon sticky">
    Stuff goes here
</div>
```

(Can only post 2 links due to a new account)

www.evernote.com/shard/s180/sh/36f1f108-907f-4ba3-9bb2-57383f24e1fd/6fcb078071e9b927ff297b7af27353ee/res/166b163a-5f51-4209-a0dd-1a6d91831675/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832

But, what I want is more like this...

[What I want](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s180/sh/bf5728ba-b6ba-4923-af58-58c5dca56381/891486c0aa18cd656bc969b65df28110/res/acfaf1a0-c217-4612-b1aa-0e49f334b4c5/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832)

But, when I add the margins in here (and change the width a bit) I end up breaking the smaller views, like so.

[Ruined responsive view](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s180/sh/2834b959-7a31-4025-a662-c77414340569/3fd0be0dbeaace8875f0190bfd0da666/res/c9578188-e90d-4a52-9ea8-ecaa20f05740/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832)

Here's the javascript I'm using to reduce by 20 pixels and add some margins.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var w = $('.coupon').css("width");
    var numW = w.replace(/\D/g,'');
    $('.coupon.large-3').css("width", (numW - 20));
    $('.coupon.large-3').css("margin", "10px 5px");
});
```

So, that's where I'm at. I'm fairly new with Foundation, as I'm sure you can tell by the question.

Anyway, what's a good way to add the margin in here like this?

Comment: it really doesnt show what you want because the 2 links do not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The links you added are not working.
I know this sounds common sense but have you read the docs about using grids in foundation?
http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/grid.html

Do you use a wrapper row like this?

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="small-2 columns">2 columns</div>
  <div class="small-10 columns">10 columns</div>
</div>
```

Performance wise its better to add an extra css class in your stylesheet instead of making a recalc in the browser with Javascript.

```
  $('.coupon.large-3').css("margin", "10px 5px");
```

Should be

```
.coupon.large-3 {
  margin:10px 5px;
}
```